# anglar2-useful-swiper not auto changing slide

Tags: angular

I am trying to integrate the `angular2-useful-swiper` to a SPA with auto rotation included to move around the images. However, it isn't transitioning at all and stays on the first page.

There are errors in the console and everything seems to be working ok (I can swipe through the slides manually, it just isn't transitioning through them).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. In my component.html is have;

```
<swiper [config]="swiperConfig" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="preview" style="background-image:url('/images/slider/slider13.jpg')">
                </div>
            </div>
/*removed for brevity*/
```

then in the component.ts I have;

```
slidesForScreenWidth: number = 1;

swiperConfig: any = {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 20,
    speed: 400,
    slidesPerView: this.slidesForScreenWidth
};
```

Am I missing a setting here?

Answer (score 1):

This is bit later.. but may help someone..!

Please make sure to import {Autoplay} module and make the swiper use it

In the module which you are using the swiper

```
import Swiper, { Autoplay} from 'swiper';
Swiper.use([Autoplay]);
```

Source - https://github.com/JayChase/angular2-useful-swiper/issues/48#issuecomment-659703770

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `autoplay` object. Then take a look at the options [you have available here](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#autoplay)

For the rotation use the `loop` option.